# How to refactor the code which uses nested if-elses?

Tags: c#, nested-if

I have some code written in C# for which I need to add some conditions. From one of my methods, I'm calling another method "UpdateData()", which updates some data into the database. Now for this, I need to add some conditions.

1. There will be appsetting in the config file, which is a boolean value. If the value is true, then the conditions in point2 have to be checked, if the value is false, it has to directly call UpdateData() method.
2. There are few types and statuses which needs be checked if the point1 is true.

   Condition 1: If type is 'A' and status is "Complete" - then call "UpdateData()".

   Condition 2 : If type is 'B' and status is "Complete" or "Partial" or "some xyz" - then call "UpdateData()".

So for this I have written the below code :

```
 bool checkStatus = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CheckStatus"]);

if (checkStatus)
{
   if (type == "A" && status == "Complete")
   {
      UpdateData();
   }
   else if (type == "B" && (status == "Complete" || status == "Other status" || status == "someother status"))
   {
      UpdateData(); // for type B , data should not be updated if status is anything other than those in condition.
   }
}
else
{
   UpdateData();
}
```

This is working as expected. But I do not want to write nested if-else. If tomorrow there is some other status and type I need to include, I need to add another if condition here.

Is there any better or optimized way of writing it?

Comment: Regardless of condition, they'll all go through `UpdateData()`, is this intentional?

Comment: @Steven, there are many values for status.the data needs to be updated only if the status is one of the tow or three mentioned in the code.

Comment: If you split those conditions into methods, so one method for A & complete, one for b & complete, or other status, or some other status, you could make 1 if, and do if (cond1() || cond(2) || !checkStatus) UpdateData

Answer (score 3):

I personally think what you have is fine. However, if you really don't like it, you could fiddle with local methods i guess

```
bool CheckA() => type == "A" && status == "Complete";
bool CheckB() => type == "B" && (status == "Complete" || status == "Other status" || status == "someother status")

if (!checkStatus || CheckA() || CheckB())
   UpdateData();
```

or

```
bool Check(string val, params string[] list) => type == val && list.Contains(status);

// uglay, yet approachable
if (!checkStatus ||
    Check("A", "Complete") ||
    Check("B", "Complete", "Other status", "someother status"))
{
   UpdateData();
}
```

<sub>***Note*** : I personally wouldn't do these, though it might be your cup of tea</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But may I know why you said you wouldn't use it. Is it not the standard way of writing it?

Comment: @CrazyCoder i just mean, i wouldn't start optimising this unless things started to get complicated and was unreadable, ie if you had to check against lists of statuses, ect. what you have is fairly readable as is

Comment: @ Okay understood. I do not want nested if-else as this would fail the quality gate set by the SonarQube. So I'm trying to avoid any nested if-else.But anyways thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @fubo you had me scratching my head there for a second :P

Comment: I have tried using the first method you have mentioned to use local functions. it is giving me compile time error : Expected; or =. I read that it is a feature in c# 6.0 . I'm using VS2015. So c# 6.0 is the default version in it. What else needs to be done to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If it is to optimise the ability to add a new one quickly, I would've put it in an array.

```
bool[] checks = new bool[]{
    (type == "A" && status == "Complete"),
    (type == "B" && (status == "Complete" || status == "Other status" || status == "someother status"))
}

if (!checkStatus || checks.Contains(false)) //'Contains' requires Linq, it also works with 'checks.Any(c => !c)'
{
    UpdateData();
}
```

This way you only need to add a new condition in the bool array and you don't have to update the if-statement for it. And you can comment out one quickly if you don't need it.

Though, it's usefulness depends on how many conditions you may expect to add.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main point of this code is to ensure the update runs when the conditions are met, which is done via unit testing.

So, I would look at how I could write this code in a testable manner so I can be sure that it does what it says on the tin.

One way to do it could be something like this:

```
public bool AppSettingsRunStatusMet(string appSettingsCheckStatus)
{
    return Convert.ToBoolean(appSettingsCheckStatus);
}

public bool TypeARunStatusMet(string type, string status)
{
   return (type.Equals("A")  && status.Equals("Complete"))
}

public bool TypeBRunStatusMet(string type, string status)
{
   return (
       type.Equals("B") && 
       ( 
            status.Equals("Complete") || 
            status.Equals("Other status") || 
            status.Equals("someother status")
       )
}
```

This is starting to shape up as a rules engine and you can have as many rules as you need

each if statement can now call one method and each rule is separated in its own method which can now be easily tested properly.

You could put all rules in their own class(es), have the engine return a status and if that status is true then run the update. The main idea is to separate config code, from the status analysis and from the code which runs the update and does whatever it is it needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer doing something like this, so that when new cases shows up or validation criteria changes we can just whitelist new case. This is simple/maintainable, works well for growing set of valid_cases with little changes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
      class Case{
        string type;
        string status;
         public Case(string type_val, string status_val ){
              status = status_val;
             type = type_val;
         }

        public override int GetHashCode()  
        {  
            return type.GetHashCode()+status.GetHashCode();  
        }  
        public override bool Equals(object obj)  
        {  
            Case test = obj as Case;  
            if (test== null)  
                return false;  
            return type == test.type &&  status == test.status ;  
        } 

    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        bool checkStatus = true;
        HashSet<Case> vaild_cases = new HashSet<Case>();
        vaild_cases.Add(new Case("A","Complete"));
        vaild_cases.Add(new Case("B","Complete"));
        vaild_cases.Add(new Case("B","Other status"));
        vaild_cases.Add(new Case("B","someother status"));
        Case current_case = new Case("A","Complete");
        if (!checkStatus || vaild_cases.Contains(current_case))
            UpdateData();
    }

    static void UpdateData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        return;
    }
}
```

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is this:

```
if((new string[] {"Complete", "Other status", "someother status"}.Contains(status) && type == "B") ||
   (status == "Complete" && type == "A") ||
   !checkStatus)
{
    UpdateData();
}
```